# Opencart first visit or depleted session to trigger lightbox form

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, opencart

On my Opencart site I'm trying to create an email subscription form for first-time visiting users, that is built within a lightbox.

So I'm approaching this through the use of a HTML lightbox form setup (initially set to display:none;) on the (home.tpl) homepage, and then though the use of JS to check the cookie validity, changing the lightbox display status from 'none' to 'block' etc.

My problem is in the actual checking of cookie validity:

What I was looking to do was something along the lines of

```
if (!isset($this->request->cookie)){
<script>//make lightbox visible.</script>
}
```

Though have played around with similar methods and none seem to work. What would be the best way of evaluating whether or not there is a valid session in place?

Also which files would you recommend manipulating in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This.

```
 <?php 
    if((isset($_GET['route']) && !isset($_SESSION[$_GET['route']])) || (!isset($_SESSION['home']) && !isset($_GET['route']) )){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    // Make your Light Box code Here
</script>  
<?php } ?>

<?php
            if(isset($_GET['route'])) {
                $_SESSION[$_GET['route']] = 1;  
            }else{
                $_SESSION['home'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['common/home'] = 1;   
            }

        ?>
```